# Android About array and layout

Tags: php, android, xml

I'm using Android Studio I don't know how to call it for this method.

in PHP when i want to loop data from SQL and show it in a group of layout.

```
$sql = "select * from <table>";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
   echo "
       <div class='box'>
          <div class='box-title'>
             <span>".$row['title']."</span>
          </div>
          <div class='box-content'>
             <span>".$row['content']."</span>
          </div>
          <div class='box-img'>
             <span>".$row['img']."</span>
          </div>
       </div>
   ";
}
```

Sorry my English is not well. I can't clearly explain.
Now back to Android Studio. I just create group of Linear Layout in XML and I want to do like my PHP ex.

Comment: This link should help you to better understand: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm learning about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I guess you need to populate list of values one by one. For this purpose you can use a `ListView` or a `RecyclerView` in Android. Both of these requires an Adapter to load data into them.

I guess it would be better to start reading from here :

- [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html)
- [this](http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html)
- [this](http://androidtuts4u.blogspot.in/2012/11/android-sqlite-and-listview-example.html)